# Redirect URIs must all belong to the same domain

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

According to the Azure Portal:

> Redirect URIs must all belong to the same domain

But I can define the following:

[image: reply url screenshot]

Why doesn't that break the rules of "the same domain"?

Comment: Very good question, I guess the downvoters stopped reading at the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks @JussiPalo.  I wish down-voters  could take the time to comment  w/ their down vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The redirect URIs must use the `https:` scheme with a single domain name.

The special case is use of the `http:` or `https:` scheme with the `localhost` host name.

This special case is allowed by [the OpenID Connect Core specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) for [an authentication request](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitAuthRequest).

Comment: But in the picture he has httpS://localhost?!

Comment: Understood, @JussiPalo, I've updated the above answer. The `http:` or `https:` scheme is allowed for the `localhost` host name. The `https:` scheme is required for any external domain name.

Comment: In my case, the only difference is my third-level domain. Ex: `bla1.blabla.com` and `bla2.blabla.com`. Do I still need to create a new account or, probably, is there any work-around for this particular case?

Comment: I don't believe there is any mention in the specification that all redirects must belong to the same domain. I can say with certainty that Keycloak, another OIDC provider, doesn't require this.